# JVM-based scripting language with Maven dependency resolution

Tags: shell, maven, scripting, classpath, dependency-management

I am looking for a simple way write short shell scripts that call into jar files.
Having to keep track of (and installing) all those jar files for the runtime classpath partly defeats the purpose using a script (as opposed to building a runnable jar file in Eclipse). I'd like Maven (or something equivalent) to manage this.

Image:

```
 #!/usr/bin/the-cool-shell

 use org.apache.commons/lang/3.0.0
 use org.json/json

 import org.json.*;

 new JSONObject("{}");
```

And this should get the required artifacts from Maven automatically (at basically zero overhead after downloading it for the first time).

What are my options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you were using Groovy and Groovy Shell you could be using the [Grape](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Grape) infrastructure.

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

@Grab( 'log4j:log4j:1.2.14' )
import org.apache.log4j.Level
import org.apache.log4j.Logger

def logger = Logger.getLogger(GroovyShell.class)
Logger.rootLogger.level = Level.INFO

logger.info 'I am using the Log4j library by using Grape'
```

As for your exact example this would work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

@Grapes([
    @Grab('org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.0'),
    @Grab('org.json:json:20090211')
    ])
import org.json.*

new JSONObject('{}')
```

In this case I was using the Groovy syntax but ordinary Java syntax is also fine.

---

Taken from the Javadoc of `@Grapes` annotation:

> Sometimes we will need more than one grab per class, but we can only add
>    one annotation type per annotatable node.  This class allows for multiple
>    grabs to be added.

Comment: That looks neat. This is part of Groovy proper, or do I need to install anything else?

Comment: No just install Groovy in some directory (`/opt/groovy` for example), make sure that the `bin` directory is in your path and then just run `groovy json.groovy` for example.

Comment: Is the `@Grapes` annotation a work-around for not being able to have multiple `@Grab` otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/overview), it's a build management tool, but it uses Groovy for its build scripts, and it uses the Maven dependency model. So your script could be a Gradle 'build' script, that just did something different than building software.